# Python 3.x input variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get user input of a code that has to be 11 numbers long and must not contain any characters. Otherwise the question to enter will be repeated.

```
code=input("Please enter your code ")
while len((code)) !=11: #here should be something to nullify strings inout :)
    code = input("Please enter your code and in numbers only ")
```

There is definitely a better solution for this, just can't think of any.

Comment: What's the *problem* with what you have? *"here should be something to nullify strings inout :)"* - the user's input is *always* a string.

Comment: problem was, that no characters are not allowed to be entered, just numbers.... I am newb at python, but got it resolved. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after

```
def validate(s):
    for char in s: #iterate through string
        if not char.isdigit(): # checks if character is not a number
            return False # if it's not a number then return False
    return True # if the string passes with no issues return True

def enter_code():
    while True: #Will keep running until break is reached
        code = input("Please enter your code: ") #get user input
# if the length of input and it passes the validate then print 'Your code is valid'
        if len(code) == 11 and validate(code):
            print('Your code is valid')
            break #break out of loop if valid
# if code fails test then print 'Your code is invalid' and return to start of while loop
        print('Your code is invalid')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    enter_code()
```

Comment: Thnx! Id don't know what's wrong with jonrsharpe, but will and try out your solution.